# How to use Google Drive API to upload files in my Drive (PHP)?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I want to make a webpage in which there will be an file input box, and the files which user uploads, should be saved into my Google Drive.

How do I achieve it using PHP?

*I don't want to use composer*

**I need refreance to a good article with some indications**

I checked on Google but I found articles to write on other's Drive, but not my own.
Also, I checked the Drive API documentation, but I think its too professional for me! Please tell me how to make a simple uploading PHP page.

Comment: You need to do some research and make some attempts yourself first. If you get stuck on something _specific_ with your code along the way, come back, show us what you've tried, the expected result and what results you're getting. Currently, this question is too broad.

Comment: _"but I found articles to write on other's Drive, but not my own"_ - I'm not sure what you mean by this, but the only difference from uploading to yours vs someone else's google drive is basically the credentials you configure.

Comment: You need to use a service account. There is documentation about this in Google's oAuth API documentation

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sir, I've checked some articles and please refer https://github.com/spjoshis/File-Uploader-To-Google-Drive-PHP which is a Github example. But I am not able to implement it as I am unaware of what "composer" is & there are several other difficulties, can you overview all steps in answer? I genuinely think that would be suitable question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What you linked is a third party library, the official way to uload files to Google Drive with the Drive API is described [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads).

Comment: _"as I am unaware of what "composer" is"_ - That has nothing to do with the library itself. Composer is the most used dependency manager for PHP. Like npm for javascript. If you're going to program using PHP, it's a good idea to learn to use composer. It will help a lot. Otherwise, you can still use the library. Just download it and include all needed files manually. It might be cumbersome for many libraries though since they are built with autoloading (through ex. composer) in mind.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson "_Just download it and include all needed files manually._" how do I do that? That's the most difficult part for me. Will you also share a link to those? Will be of great help. (Answer ths - so that I can accept)

Comment: How to do what? Download code from github or how to include files in PHP? I would strongly recommend that you google something like _"getting started with composer"_ and learn about that instead. Composer is today more or less the norm for using third party dependencies. Some libraries are also depending on other libraries, which composer automatically solves for you. If you do it manually, you need to download and include all those files as well, which very quickly becomes really messy.

Comment: both. because I'm not sure what files are needed (from Github) for uploading to drive. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for suggesting composer, but I don't want to use composer

Comment: _"but I don't want to use composer"_ - Do you have a valid reason for it, or is it just "I don't want to because I don't want to"? If you don't want to, then you need to read githubs manual about how to use their site (like how to download code) and then read the php manual about using `include` and `require`. Do some research and make some attempts. If you then get stuck on something _specific_, come back, show us what you've tried, what you expect to happen and what actually happens.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Sir, just let me know which files to `require` & all problems will be solved.

Comment: You're asking us for A LOT here. We would need to go through the whole library and see what files uses what classes etc. to know what files you need to include from it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson can I edit this question & will you then answer?

Comment: Before you ask us for help, you _need_ to make some proper research and make some real attempts yourself, or the question will  You've shown no effort from your part but expect us to spend a bunch of time to solve it for you. The question is too broad. I've given you some pointers so go from there and try something.

Comment: Can you link the  "articles to write on other's Drive, but not my own"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Upload to Google Drive with the Google Drive API - without composer

What you need for integrating the feature with a Website:

- Install the [google-api-php-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php)
- Install the [Google_DriveService client](https://github.com/marcj/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php)
- No matter how you upload files to Google Drive - you need some kind of credentials to show that you have access to the Drive in question (that is you need to authenticate as yourself).For this:

  - If not already done - set up (for free) the Google Cloud console.
  - Create a [project](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects#creating_a_project).
  - Enable the [Drive API](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/getting-started#enabling_apis).
  - Set up a [consent screen](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en).
  - Go to `APIs & Services -> Credentials` and `+Create Credentials`
  - There are several possibilities, in your case, it makes  sense to create an `OAuth client ID` and chose `Application type: Web Application`
  - Specify the URL of your website with the form as `Authorized JavaScript origins` and `Authorized redirect URIs`
  - After creating the client - note down the `client ID` and `client secret`

Now, you can put together Google's sample for [authentication with the OAuth2 client](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/code_samples/php) with the creation of the [Google Drive service object](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php) and [Uploading to Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads), then incorporate it into a [PHP File Upload](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp).

**Patching those code snippets together could look like following:**

*form.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Select image to upload:
  <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

*upload.php*

```php
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';
//create a Google OAuth client
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId('YOUR CLIENT ID');
$client->setClientSecret('YOUR CLIENT SECRET');
$redirect = filter_var('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
    FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));
if(empty($_GET['code']))
{
    $client->authenticate();
}

if(!empty($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]))
{
  $target_file=$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
  // Create the Drive service object
  $accessToken = $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
  $service = new Google_DriveService($client);
  // Create the file on your Google Drive
  $fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
    'name' => 'My file'));
  $content = file_get_contents($target_file);
  $mimeType=mime_content_type($target_file);
  $file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
    'data' => $content,
    'mimeType' => $mimeType,
    'fields' => 'id'));
  printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);
}
?>
```

Comment: @RaviPrakash Not sure, but you can always rectify that now.

Comment: Now today, I got the "accept" option (using desktop and Chrome)

Comment: Dear Sir, @ziganotschka, How do I "Install"?  google-api-php-client & Google_DriveService client? If you simply mean to download the folder from Github, then it would be much easier to understand. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, just downloading should be possible.

Comment: @ziganotschka Do I need anything more than these two folders?

Comment: `use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface;` is in the file `google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php` And that folder is absent.

Comment: Client.php is not a folder, but a file -as for the folder-you can manually create it or change the path variable to adapt to your existing folder.

Comment: Can you please explain how to download those files and where to store them? I am completely new to these APIs. (I'm good in PHP)

Comment: Please respond @ziganotschka on my above comment

Comment: Suppose you have a PHP enabled hosting, how do you make this work? Which files to be downloaded? Please explain in detail. please. @ziganotschka

Comment: @ziganotschka There's no such file `/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php` and there's no directory `contrib`

Comment: In my answer I provided the link to the [Google_DriveService client library](https://github.com/marcj/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/contrib/Google_DriveService.php). Since you do not not want to sue composer, all you need is to copy-paste the library into a `Google_DriveService.php` file that you create on your machine. The path under which you create this file needs to correspond to the one you specify under `require_once`.

Comment: @ziganotschka HOW TO JUST SMPLY UPLOAD IN MY DRIVE? (Why using your code leads to an Auth? I don't want to access anyone's drive by logging in, I just simply silently want files uploaded in my drive.)

Comment: do you have any instructions on how to ïnstall "google-api-php-client".  The link above is not available.