# Google drive error while uploading the file from laravel

Tags: laravel, file-upload, google-drive-api

throw this error
Google_Exception
(list) unknown parameter: 'maxResults'

```
// code 

 $eod = new Eod;
 $eod->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
 $eod->save();
 $folderName = time();
$donationInfo = Society::where('eod_id', $eod->id)->first();
$pdf = \PDF::loadView('pdf.society', compact('donationInfo'));
$fileName = 'society_army-' . $eod->id . '.pdf';
\Storage::disk('public')->put('downloads/donation_' . $folderName . '/' . $fileName,  $pdf->output());

$fileAddress = storage_path().'downloads/donation_' . 'downloads/donation_' . $folderName . '/' . $fileName;
$file = new UploadedFile($fileAddress, 'file');
$request->files->set("file['.$j.']", $file);
$drive_result   = $this->uploadToGoogleDrive($request, \App\Client::find($request->client_id)->getFullNameAttribute(), $fileName, 'DonationReceipt');
```

my running website throwing this error while uploading the file on google drive. My logic is to create a pdf and uploaded it to google drive everything running fine for years but now I am seeing this error. Is anyone has any idea about this

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing any code. Can you post what you are exactly doing, where the error happens, what the exact error message is? Which (Google) API is involved?

Comment: ok, I update the code in post

Comment: Where is this parameter coming from? Can you share where this parameter is created and the function to upload files to drive?

Comment: I update the code block all the parameters are now code section.

Comment: The max results parameter is not in the code. Also, could the answer from this post help you?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63648331/how-to-use-google-drive-api-to-upload-files-in-my-drive-php

Comment: after reviewing it again this problem is at development environment, i thinks i need to add my development environment IP in google API key.